# Android: DatePicker value saved in a variable doesn't go in onCreate

Tags: android, android-studio, datepicker

I have a rather simple issue but this is bugging me out!
I am trying to build an app in which I have 2 DatePickers, periodFrom and periodTo.
Basically what I'm trying to do is let the user pick dates on both cases and then calculate the difference between dates in days. I already know how to get the difference, how to get the date from the DatePicker. The problem is I don't know where I should get the value from the DatePicker, as my onCreate intializes the listener for the DatePickers but it doesn't store the set dates in the global variables, only the current date which it gets from `Calendar.getInstance();`

Here is my code for the MainActivity, maybe you can enlighten me on this issue I'm having. Thank you!

`MainActivity.class`

```
package com.endtech.utilitycalculator;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText periodFrom, periodTo;
private Calendar mCalendarFrom = Calendar.getInstance();
private Calendar mCalendarTo = Calendar.getInstance();
private long from, to;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    periodFrom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.periodFrom);
    periodTo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.periodTo);

    initListeners();
    from = mCalendarFrom.getTimeInMillis(); //This is current time, not the set time
    to = mCalendarTo.getTimeInMillis(); //This is current time, not the set time
}

private void initListeners() {
    setDateFrom();
    setDateTo();
}

private void setDateFrom() {
    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            mCalendarFrom.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            mCalendarFrom.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            mCalendarFrom.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateLabelFrom();
        }
    };

    periodFrom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, date, mCalendarFrom.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    mCalendarFrom.get(Calendar.MONTH), mCalendarFrom.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    });
}

private void updateLabelFrom() {
    String mFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(mFormat, Locale.GERMANY);

    periodFrom.setText(sdf.format(mCalendarFrom.getTime()));
}

private void setDateTo() {
    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date2 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            mCalendarTo.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            mCalendarTo.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            mCalendarTo.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateLabelTo();
        }
    };

    periodTo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, date2, mCalendarTo.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    mCalendarTo.get(Calendar.MONTH), mCalendarTo.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    });
}

private void updateLabelTo() {
    String mFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(mFormat, Locale.GERMANY);

    periodTo.setText(sdf.format(mCalendarTo.getTime()));
}
```

}

Comment: Then your question is ?

Comment: Where can I get the value from the calendar, after I set the date? such that I can use that value in my onCreate. Because onCreate I just initialize the listeners and passes through very fast so it doesn't register my variable again. I don't know if you get my point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are getting the dates before selecting them.

Simply Create a button (when you click on the button then the process of converting difference into days get done). then on button click get the values of dates and then convert it into days.

Let me know if you find some problem by commenting below.

Comment: Thank you. This was also what I was thinking... but I didn't want to add a button.. Anyway, the behaviour is correct and you deserve to have to correct answer to this topic.

Comment: Then you can do the same thing when you select periodTo, but make sure you have selected periodFrom. or put a condition that if periodFrom is selected then only find days.